# How do I set my account preferences and get notified by emails when there is an answer for me?

Tags: support

The title says it. I am surfing like crazy through askubuntu.com, but I cannot find out how to set my preferences. I must be blind, or the New Year's party went too long... Forgive me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to your [Preferences page here](https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/current) for all your preferences.

You can also go to your [user page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current) (accessible from your user icon in the topbar) and click "preferences".

Comment: Thanks. I really wonder why I could not find these pages starting from the askubuntu homepage. Am I blind, or is there really no link?

Comment: just press the avatar along your reputation in the black bar.